# Javascript create WebSocket connection refused - content security

Tags: javascript, websocket, connection, content-security-policy, connection-refused

Trying to open a WebSocket connection from a Browser to a server running on localhost:9000 here is my JS code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var url = "ws://localhost:9000/myapp";
    var connection = new WebSocket(url);

    connection.onopen = function() {
        console.log('WebSocket Open');
    };
    connection.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);
    };
    connection.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('WebSocket Msg ', event);
    }

});
```

But the browser is refusing to accept the connection due to Content-security policy:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at ws://localhost:9000/myapp ("default-src
>   http://localhost:9000").

I thought that openning a websocket connection to "self" in this case "localhost" would be acceptable but both Chrome and FF are denying the connection. I thought of placing

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src http: ws: connect-src ws:">
```

but it didn't fix the problem.

These are the headers being returned by the Server:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
> X-Frame-Options: DENY
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
> X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: master-only
> Date: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 03:39:10 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 2130
> ```

What could be causing the connection refusal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like that page must be getting served with a `Content-Security-Policy` response header that has `default-src http://localhost:9000` in its value.

Given that you can never use a CSP directive somewhere to apply a more-liberal policy than one applied from somewhere else, if you have a strict `default-src http://localhost:9000` policy in the CSP header, it’ll be applied instead of any more-liberal policy you might have specified using a `meta` element in a document.

See [the discussion about multiple policies in the CSP spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#multiple-policies):

> The impact is that adding additional policies to the list of policies to enforce can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected resource.

So I think you may need to change value of the `Content-Security-Policy` header to have `default-src http: ws: connect-src ws:`. You can’t do it with just a `meta` element.